# removing / exchanging html content using media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Since video-backgrounds usually do not play automatically on hand held devices, I would like to remove the video and replace it with a bg image depending on the screen size.

What is the best way to achieve this? Is it possible to do with media queries? :)

Comment: @AtonAskling what language is the site written in?

Comment: Tags are html5 and css so Im guessing he's talking about a html video tag :)

Answer (score 1):

You can actually have an image set to the video tag on the HTML, so if the video isnt supported, it displays an image. This is usually the easiest way to have an image load when you are on mobile for example, instead of having a separate webpage for mobile. You can read more about how to do this here:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/

Answer (score 0):

Best method IMO would be to detect if the user is coming from Mobile device or standard device using their User Agent and then show the video background on standard devices, and show the background image on the mobile devices.

Depending on the language you're using for the site, detecting a mobile device using the user-agent is relatively simple.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have an different piece of code to execute depending on the device the user is watching your website from, I suggest you use `@media queries`.

**Targeting smartphones**:

Not all smartphones are the same size, but as a general rule of thumb use:

```
@media screen and (device-width: 360px)
  and (device-height: 640px)
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
    .imageelement {
        /* Your css code*/
        display: block !important;
    }
    .videoelement {
        /* Your css code*/
        display: none !important;
    }
```

}

**Targeting tablets**:

When targeting tablets you should keep the dimensions to this range:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    .imageelement {
        /* Your css code*/
        display: block !important;
    }
    .videoelement {
        /* Your css code*/
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

**Targeting laptops and larger devices**:

Finally, this is where you want to put your video to appear.

```
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    .imageelement {
        /* Your css code*/
        display: none !important;
    }
    .videoelement {
        /* Your css code*/
        display: block !important;
    }
```

}

If you want to know more about `@media queries` visit [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).